# Data corrupted after download through php form

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
<?php
global $table;
global $act;
global $upload;

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}
include('db_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['choose_lang']))
{ 
    $table = $_POST['choose_lang'];
 } 
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $act = $_POST['action'];
    }
if(isset($_GET['upload']))
{
    $upload = $_GET['upload'];
    }
$upload = $_GET['upload'];

$_SESSION['upload'] = $upload;

$table = $_SESSION['choose_lang'];
$act=$_SESSION['action'];

   $query = "SELECT  *   FROM  $table WHERE upload = '".$_SESSION['upload']."' AND    category = '$act'" ;

 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
 $size = $row['filesize1'];

 $type = $row['filetype1'];
 $name =$row['filexml'];

 $text = $row['data1'];

 header("Content-length:".$size);
 header("Content-type:".$type);
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name);
 readfile("$text");
 echo $text;
 ?>
```

My Output Should Contain the Following when Downloaded:

```
   File type = "ooTextFile"
   Object class = "TextGrid"

   xmin = 0 
   xmax = 2.264331065759637 
   tiers? <exists> 
   size = 1 
   item []: 
   item [1]:
    class = "IntervalTier" 
    name = "vowels" 
    xmin = 0 
    xmax = 2.264331065759637 
    intervals: size = 5 
    intervals [1]:
        xmin = 0 
        xmax = 0.9286507897337561 
        text = "" 
    intervals [2]:
        xmin = 0.9286507897337561 
        xmax = 1.0970767840615319 
        text = "a" 
    intervals [3]:
        xmin = 1.0970767840615319 
        xmax = 1.2213912084463185 
        text = "" 
    intervals [4]:
        xmin = 1.2213912084463185 
        xmax = 1.447964272244398 
        text = "e" 
    intervals [5]:
        xmin = 1.447964272244398 
        xmax = 2.264331065759637 
        text = ""
```

Rather the Output Comes as in a notepad file when opened:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
     File type = "ooTextFile"
     Object class = "TextGrid"

      xmin = 0 
      xmax = 2.264331065759637 
      tiers? <exists> 
     size = 1 
  item []: 
 item [1]:
    class = "IntervalTier" 
    name = "vowels" 
    xmin = 0 
    xmax = 2.264331065759637 
    intervals: size = 5 
    intervals [1]:
        xmin = 0 
        xmax = 0.9286507897337561 
        text = "" 
    intervals [2]:
        xmin = 0.9286507897337561 
        xmax = 1.0970767840615319 
        text = "a" 
    intervals [3]:
        xmin = 1.0970767840615319 
        xmax = 1.2213912084463185 
        text = "" 
    intervals [4]:
        xmin = 1.2213912084463185 
        xmax = 1.447964272244398 
        text = "e" 
    intervals [5]:
        xmin = 1.447964272244398 
        xmax = 2.264331065759637 
        text = ""
```

Thus my file gets corrupt. WHere Is the Error. Kindly HELP!!!! where from the HTML Body Comes.

Comment: You probably have boiler plate that is being included automatically. Where is this script being called from?

Comment: from a php form from where this textgrid file cn be downloaded

Comment: The php script you posted is the `action` of a form, did I understand that right? boiler plate just means standard text that was copied from somewhere.

Comment: so kindly help me hw cn i solve this. Similar problem is for another download script where the dowloaded mp3 file is corrupt. There also html body is added automatically

Comment: I am guessing there is something happening in `db_connection.php`

Comment: actualy i select a language then its category and i get this file from Library (choose_lang= language variable) (action= category variable) and Upload is Primary key(id) and clicking the link above mentioned download script runs to download this file

Comment: `global $table;
global $act;
global $upload;` tells me some other php file is most likely invoking this script. Where is that code?

Comment: Thank Youa  LOt TIM yes the prblm was with db_connection .php

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework or CMS? They might do tricky stuff. Then it might be better to just save the file (temporary) and link to that so the user downloads a physical file..
If it's your own system, then you can backtrace to where this HTML was generated.

Comment: Thnx TIM it is Solved the html was from db_connection.php it was takin garbage!!!!